# Negative int to hexadecimal conversion

Tags: java

I am converting some integers to hexadecimals but the problem i have is when i pass a negative value to convert it to hex.

Example:

```
String satpos = "13.0";
String satposs=satpos.replaceAll("\\.", ""); 
int satposition = Integer.parseInt(satposs);
String nids = Integer.toHexString(satposition);
String finished = nids+"0000";
```

Application returns "820000" in this case and that is the correct value i need.
But if i pass:

```
String satpos = "-7.0";
String satposs=satpos.replaceAll("\\.", ""); 
int satposition = Integer.parseInt(satposs);
String nids = Integer.toHexString(satposition);
String finished = nids+"0000";
```

Application returns "ffffffba0000" but i should get "DCA0000"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why `-70` should be `DCA`?

Comment: I am developing a satfinder app which takes all the info about channel and makes a unique id which can be used to "call" the channel from DVB reciever and the explanation which i got from dev is:

`orbital position is 13,0 - turn it in 130 (dec) => 82 (hex) - add 0000. Final result namespace = 820000`

in this case orbital position of this channel is -7.0

Comment: What representation do you intend for negative integers? Java is based on using 2's complement. The hex representation of 70 is 46, and its 2's complement is ffffffba. If you want a different representation for negative integers, you need to specify it and do the conversion.

Comment: also, what if orbital position is "13.00", what should you get?

Comment: it's 13.0 -> 130 to hex = 82, i only have so much variations, maybe 5-6 negative ints and 10-15 positive, positive ones return correct values and i can actualy use thos values to communicate with my DVB device so it means those values are correct

Comment: You keep telling us about the non-controversial positive numbers. What representation do you want for the negative ones?

Comment: @Psycho I dont see in you code conversion from "13.00" to "13.0"

Comment: The key point is the *"turn it"* phrase in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286855/negative-int-to-hexadecimal-conversion#comment62098889_37286855), which implies that the value is a degree. A negative value like `-7°` means turn the other way, but turning `7°` the other way is the same as `360° - 7° = 353°` the normal way. And `3530` (dec) is `DCA` (hex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a comment by Andreas, here is a test program that prints the values you want:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    convert("13.0");
    convert("-7.0");
  }

  private static void convert(String satpos) {
    String satposs = satpos.replaceAll("\\.", "");
    int satposition = Integer.parseInt(satposs);
    if (satposition < 0) {
      satposition += 3600;
    }
    String nids = Integer.toHexString(satposition);
    String finished = nids + "0000";
    System.out.println(finished);
  }

}
```

If the angle is negative, add 3600 because the angle is in tenths of a degree.

Comment: Thank you, i was not thinking about it in degrees, now it is all clear as day. 
You all people helped so much